# Find all the real Zeros of the function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[image]

Please help me I'm stuck and I don't know how to go about this. :(

Comment: **Guess** some easy roots. For example, in case, you know the  possible rational ones are $\;\pm\{1,3,9\}\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick called factoring by grouping: $$x^3-3x+3x^2-9=x(x^2-3)+3(x^2-3)=(x+3)(x^2-3)$$ Can you take it from here?

Granted, an example has to be pretty contrived for you even to be able to do this, but for the sake of a pre-calculus class, it can be useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try to use [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

If the coefficient of the highest power is +/- 1 , 
then any rational root must be an integer dividing the constant term. 
If you have found such a root (say u), 
reduce the degree of the polynomial by dividing it by x-u.

If the coefficient of the highest power is not 1, then the possible roots $\frac{u}{v}$

with gcd(u,v)=1 must satisfy the conditions :

u divides the constant term.

v divides the coefficient of the highest power.

Again, you can reduce the degree by dividing by vx-u.

If the final degree is 2, you can use the formula for quadratic equations.
 If not, the best way to find roots is the bisection-method or the newton-method.